# Kannada font different in Firefox and Chrome browsers

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, language-support

Recently I am observing change in font style for Kannada language in Firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04. 
[image]

Left is Chrome and right one from Firefox.

Here, expected is font style seen in Chrome.
Same difference can be seen in many other sites in Firefox.

What could be going wrong here?
Is it issue with Firefox or Ubuntu?

Please clarify.

Comment: I don't know Kannada, so I can't tell if what you showed is just a style difference or there's something completely wrong, but recently Firefox changed the fonts for Tamil to a different style, arguably less readable. I assumed this was just an aesthetic decision... if I don't like it, I should send feedback to Mozilla? [here's an image for comparison](https://i.imgur.com/e6d8PbI.png)

Comment: Yes... its a change in font style and is less readable. Here, issue is why font style is different in Firefox than in Chrome and is less readable?

Comment: I just went into about:preferences on Firefox and changed the default font for Tamil (go into Advanced next to fonts and select font for your language from the dropdown) and selected Lohit Tamil - the font went back to the more readable, less decorative style. So I think Firefox chose to change the default to the more fancy style. Does the same work for you? (I mean, there is a Lohit Kannada too...) (if that workaround is helpful, it could be posted as an answer)

Comment: Yes... It worked! :) I changed to Lohit Kannada and text is now more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we need to change font for Kannada to "Lohit Kannada" in

*about:preferences -> Fonts & Colors -> Fonts -> Advanced*.

[image]

Then, after refresh of the page in Firefox, I got font style as expected.

[image]

Thanks to @Zanna for the answer.